# Pass + operator in requests.get method

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to send + in URL request but it replaced with empty space.

```
import urllib

args = {"key": "+ 919191xxxx", "secret": "+ 98989"}
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?{}".format(urllib.urlencode(args))
```

Anyone can help me to resolve this?

Comment: The result of `urllib.urlencode(args)` is `'secret=%2B+98989&key=%2B+919191xxxx'`. `%2B` is the code for `+`. There is no empty space

Comment: how should url look like?

Comment: thanks @EvansMurithi, can you please tell me how can I double URLencode this string?

Answer (score 0):

The `+` is not being replaced by space but with `%2B` which is the escape of `+`.

In your view, you can use [urllib.unquote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) to replace escapes by their equivalent character like so:

```
from urllib import unquote

key = unquote(request.GET.get('key', ''))
secret = unquote(request.GET.get('secret', ''))
```